# How to load a json using mmap in python? (on windows)

Tags: python, json, unicode, utf-8, mmap

I have a json file which I open using memory map in python. I provide the size as 1024 even though the json_file doesnt contain that many field. When I do the `json.loads(...)` I get the `Error: raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)`. I open the json file and see that there are `NULL` character at the end. See this image: [image: nullcharacters]

I am not sure on the proper way to load the json file. My code to open the mmap file and load the json is below.

```
The json file has contents shown below:
{
    "Gardens": {
        "Seaside": {
            "@loc": "porch",
            "@myID": "1.2.3",
            "Tid": "1",
            "InfoList": {
                "status": {
                    "@default": "0",
                    "@myID": "26"
                },
                "count": {
                    "@default": "0",
                    "@myID": "1"
                }
            },
            "BackYard": {
                "@loc": "backyard",
                "@myID": "75",
                "Tid": "2",
                "InfoList": {
                    "status": {
                        "@default": "6",
                        "@myID": "32"
                    },
                    "count": {
                        "@default": "0",
                        "@myID": "2"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
} #  There are NULL characters here as doing the mmap fills NULL characters as the size of the file provided is 1024
```

```
        # Open and read file and MMAP (WRITE access)
        json_file = open(json_path, "r+", encoding="utf-8")
        mapped_file = mmap.mmap(json_file.fileno(), 1024, access=mmap.ACCESS_WRITE)

        # Create the mmap file buffer
        mappedFile.seek(0)
        file_size = os.path.getsize(json_path)
        buffer_for_json = mappedFile[:file_size]

        # Content is JSON, so load it
        json_data = json.loads(buffer_for_json.decode("utf-8")) # ERROR: raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
```

I am really lost and not sure on how to solve this. Any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: Are you using Windows? The [docs for the Windows version of `mmap.mmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html#mmap.mmap) say: _"If_ length _is larger than the current size of the file, the file is extended to contain_ length _bytes."_

Comment: O sorry, I just saw it says Windows in the title.

Answer (score 1):

I can't test this, because I don't have Windows to test the Windows version of `mmap.mmap`, but I think this is happening:

When you call `mmap.mmap()` with a length value larger than the file size, the original file on disk is changed.
The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html#mmap.mmap) say:

> If *length* is larger than the current size of the file, the file is extended to contain *length* bytes.

Most probably, the file is padded with null bytes to the size of 1024 bytes (what you specified).
And 1024 is also what you get from `os.path.getsize(json_path)` afterwards.
That's why `mappedFile[:file_size]` contains these trailing null bytes.

I suggest you set the mmap length conditionally, eg.:

```
json_file = open(json_path, "r+", encoding="utf-8")
length = min(1024, os.path.getsize(json_path))
mapped_file = mmap.mmap(json_file.fileno(), length, access=mmap.ACCESS_WRITE)
```

This should avoid null-byte padding (which also permanently corrupts your JSON file, btw.).

Comment: I will try it and let you know in a couple of hours. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

That happened to me when I don't `import json` at the beginning.

The default encoding is 'utf-8' so I don't think is necessary to specify that. You could also try `json_data = json.loads(buffer_for_json.decode())` or 
`json_data = json.loads(buffer_for_json)`

You can read more about json [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) and

Comment: I solved the issue by ```buffer_for_json.decode("utf-8").rstrip('\0')```. But I have another issue. When I write the json_string back to the mmap file, I get an extra '}' at the end of the mmap json file. Do you have any idea why this could happen?

Comment: @al29 I can't imagine that you get a `JSONDecodeError` if you forget to import the `json` module – rather, you'd get a `NameError`. Also, we don't close questions here when they're answered – that happens only when they're off-topic.

Comment: @lenz You are right. Sorry about that. I got confused with the issue system